# I would like to make a Pinterest Layout on my Feed?

Tags: python, html, css

0

I am triying to make my Feed Page for my Social Media Website look cool. Right now the Feed shows the Posts (Images and Videos) one below each other, like Instagram f. e. I want to have 2 Posts next to each other, like Pinterest f. e.

[what I want (click to see)] https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBGNg.png

I code my Webiste with HTML, CSS and PYTHON.

feed.html

```
    <article class="content-section" style="overflow: auto;">
      
      <div class="mediacontent">
   {% if post.extension == '.mp4'%}
     <video loop class="video-context" width="500px" height="500px" controls>
            <source src="{{ post.file.url }}" type="video/mp4">
         </video>
   {% elif post.extension == '.jpg' or post.extension == '.jpeg' %}
  <a href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}">
      <img class="image-context" src="{{ post.file.url }}">
    </a>
   {% endif %}
  </div>
  
  <div class="initials">
   <div class="media">
    <div class="img-cont3">
      <a href="{% url 'profile-detail-view' post.author.pk %}"><img class="rounded-circle article-img feed-pic" src="{{post.author.profile.image.url}}" alt="image"></a>
      
    </div>
    <div class="media-body">
      
        <span><a class="mr-2 full-name-link" href="{% url 'profile-detail-view' post.author.pk %}">{{ post.author.first_name }} {{ post.author.last_name }} </a></span>
      <span><a href="{% url 'profile-detail-view' post.author.pk %}"><small class="text-muted at-username">w/{{ post.author }}</small></a></span>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
  var videos = document.querySelectorAll('video');
for(var i=0; i<videos.length; i++)
   videos[i].addEventListener('play', function(){pauseAll(this)}, true);

function pauseAll(elem){
    for(var i=0; i<videos.length; i++){
        //Is this the one we want to play?
        if(videos[i] == elem) continue;
        //Have we already played it && is it already paused?
        if(videos[i].played.length > 0 && !videos[i].paused){
        // Then pause it now
          videos[i].pause();
        }
    }
  }
</script>

<br>

  <h3 class="article-title">{{ post.title }}</h3>
  <a href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}">
    <p class="interactions">{{post.total_likes}} <span>Likes</span></p></a>
        
    </article>
```

style.css

```
.media {
  height: 55px;
}

  .media-body span{
    display: block;
    margin-top: -3px;
  }

  body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }

  .like-info {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
    color: #535353;
    font-weight: 500;
  }

  .article-title span {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 500;
  }

  .article-title span:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  .article-title {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
    color: #535353;
    font-weight: 400;
  }

  
.interactions {
  color: #000;
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.interactions span{
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif, sans-serif;
  color: #535353;
  font-weight: 500;
}



  .content-section {
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    border: 1px #9d9d9d dashed;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }


  .content-section-upload {
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: none;
    padding-right: -10px;
    padding-left: -10px;
    padding-bottom: -60px;
    padding-top: -60px;
  }



  .create-section {
    width: 100%;
  }


  


  .image-context {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
  }


  .video-context {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    max-height: 450px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

an more Styles that is not related to the main issue.

Is it possible to grid 2 Posts next to each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!-- demo for pinterest like layout with responsiveness -->
**HTML:**

<div class="app">
<div class="feed">
<img src="" />
<!-- More images -->
</div>
</div>

**css:**
.app{
width: 80vw;
margin: auto;
}

.feed{
column: 4 12rem; /* 1st one is column count and second one is width */
}
```